# CSV file generation from HTML inputted data

Tags: javascript, html, sas

I was trying to pass user inputted data in HTML form to csv file on local drive.
 But seems some error in it.

I have tried below code even that is copied from other sources.

```
    <html>
  <head>
  <script language="javascript">
    function WriteToFile(passForm) {
      var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
      var fileLoc = "C:\\sample.txt";
      var file = OpenTextFile(fileLoc,2,true,0);
     file.write("File handling in Javascript");
      file.Close();
      alert('File created successfully at location: ' + fileLoc);
     }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p>create a csv file with following details -</p>
  <form>
    Type your first name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" size="20"><br>
    Type your last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" size="20"><br>
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="WriteToFile(this.form)">
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
</br></br></html>
```

CSV file is not getting created and cant get any error in HTML.

Comment: Place a #debugger in your javascript code for general debugging. However from this script, you cannot write to C:\ as admin rights are required which should not be available to browser context (security risk). Also  check the trust level in your IE setting to figure out if ActiveX is allowed to run or not

Comment: Under normal circumstances it is not possible to read or write files on the clients hard drive directly. I think the code you got here is some specific stuff for the Internet explorer. Maybe it is to be executed on the server-side in an ASP component? However, you can create files in javascript and show a button to save/download it.

Comment: @nitinsingh : I am not able to write anywhere leave alone C drive.

Comment: @lupz : Any code snippet for getting the same file created on my local machine? actually i need to integrate it in my SAS code and i am bit new to this(HTMl and javascript)

Comment: Are you using a SAS server ? Is your SAS code in a SAS stored process ?

Comment: @Richard It is a normal macro written in base sas

Comment: @vaibjav I don't have any idea on SAS. Have a look at the second solution of [Rubens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56151091/1167428). That's the way I'd go.

Comment: @lupz : Yes it seems to download the file but I want to append the data to existing csv file. So I am still struggling to find my answer.

Comment: What about keeping _all the current data/state_ on the server side? Whenever the user submits the form it will get updated. Additionally whenever she or he wants to do so the user can download the complete document.

Comment: @lupz : Actually problem is : I just want to create this page for our monitoring team to feed the data. It is on the same server as the data, hence talking of saving the data locally. I have tried pretty much everything suggested here but no luck!

Answer (score 2):

You were not using the variable fso to call OpenTextFile, you should also keep in mind that IE has permissions to write in the path

This should work for you:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        function WriteToFile(passForm) {
            var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
            var fileLoc = "C:\\Users\\yourUser\\sample.csv";
            var file = fso.OpenTextFile(fileLoc,2,true,0);
            file.write("File handling in Javascript");
            file.Close();
            alert('File created successfully at location: ' + fileLoc);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>create a csv file with following details -</p>
    <form>
        Type your first name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" size="20"><br>
        Type your last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" size="20"><br>
        <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="WriteToFile(this.form)">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also use this solution that works for several browsers:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        function downloadCSV(form) {
            const content = 'Write your csv content here!!';
            const mimeType = 'text/csv;encoding:utf-8';
            const fileName = 'download.csv';
            const a = document.createElement('a');

            if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE10
                navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([content], {
                    type: mimeType
                }), fileName);
            } else if (URL && 'download' in a) { //html5 A[download]
                a.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([content], {
                    type: mimeType
                }));
                a.setAttribute('download', fileName);
                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
                document.body.removeChild(a);
            } else {
                location.href = 'data:application/octet-stream,' + encodeURIComponent(content); // only this mime type is supported
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>create a csv file with following details -</p>
    <form>
        Type your first name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" size="20"><br>
        Type your last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" size="20"><br>
        <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="downloadCSV(this.form)">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thing is : With downloading the file I can pretty much redirect it to the desired location. So I guess this might somewhat sort my problem.Can you pls help me in getting the inputted data into the file rather than sample content. It might be pretty simple but i am not a javascript guy, so struggling to do this